# How to add toolbar under actionbar - android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

My friend made for me a toolbar code and it must be under action bar. How to add it to main ml layout and also to main java activity?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/laytop_imgwidthheight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/laytop_imgwidthheight"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.commonutility.RoundImageView android:id="@+id/image_view_country_flag"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/country_default_logo"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:background="@color/md_grey_300"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/credits_bar_credits_label"
            android:textColor="@color/md_grey_700"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/credit_wallet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/md_grey_700"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:padding="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_300"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But now i haven't got a contact with him. How to add it to main xml and also main java activity?

Please help guys!

Comment: You can not add toolbar under action bar.. you have to add custom toolbar using layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom tool bar( separate xml file is preferable because we can reuse it ) and include it your  xml file, using include tag.

```
<include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

here 'toolbar' is an xml file(contains toolbar design) at layout folder.

if you want to remove action bar then you set the 'parent' property of style.xml as 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```